# Utilizing 100% Network in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, networking, multiprocessing

I'm currently trying to grab files from multiple servers simultaneously in the fastest way possible. I've written Python script that uses Paramiko to SCP all files to my computer. I thought threading would do the trick but when I run the script it I can see only 60% of my network being utilized. Even when I change thread count from 50 -> 100 there doesn't seem to be any difference. I discovered that threads are just actually running on the same core and the GIL prevents threads from working simultaneously; threads are just switching between each other REALLY quickly.

I moved on to trying to use multiprocessing, looking into it it seems you should only spawn Process's for the number of cores you have; 4 in my case. When I run it, my CPU is maxed out at 99% usage, and my Network is at 0%, though it seems that files are slowly being transferred...

My question is how do I utilize 100% to maximize my download speed and decrease download time? Spawn Processes that spawn threads?

Comment: Use less threads, better: use no threads Physically network packet come sequentially, not in parallel. Read larger buffers, Python3 and async will help. To get around 100% you need a better understanding of network stack, your kernel and routers configurations, etc. It is a complex topic.

Comment: agree to @Giacomo Catenazzi, use coroutine for the job and plus multiprocess too